# Google's AJAX CDN

Tags: cdn

Does any one know how to access the Claro css file for version 1.3.2 I tried this link but it did not work?

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css

Comment: Can you use version 1.5? It has that?

Comment: I would prefer not to. My company is using version 1.3.2 and I see the css is not on the aol cdn also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the older releases of dojo, there isn't a claro theme for the 1.3 branch - see here:

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.3.3/dojo-release-1.3.3/dijit/themes/

In fact, it looks like this was a new theme added in release 1.5:

http://docs.dojocampus.org/releasenotes/1.5#claro-theme

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I might have to just deal with using version 1.5.